# quotes problem in very simple sql

Tags: php, sql

I just simply want to execute a SQL sentence inside of a post (i am using EXEC-PHP widget for that).

The problem are the quotes when i want to do something like

$my_name='hello'

"select * from Table where name='$my_name'";

getting wrong quotes.... select * from Table where name=‘hello‘

i have tried streepslashes_deep, addslashes, stripslashes...

I think it shouldnt be so difficult... maybe its not my best day

any help?

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

if you're communicating with the WordPress database itself, try using `$wpdb->prepare()` on your select string before running it as `$wpdb->query()` - it should format it for you.

Further reading: [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Protect_Queries_Against_SQL_Injection_Attacks)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the plugin is modifying your single quotes. Double quotes are valid in SQL. What happens if you use double quotes and escape them?

e.g. "select * from Table where name=\"$my_name\"";

Answer (score 0):

Try seperating and concatenating stringss:

```
'select * from Table where name="'.$my_name.'"';
```